# Getting Image in django teplate from ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

It is returning an error : Not Found: /post-detail/6/images/wallpaper002.jpg. I have tried to show image through {{ post_detail.img.all.first.url }} but I could show image in the template, it returns None value.

news.html

'''

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img class="detail_picture img-thumbnail" src="{{ post_detail.img.all.first }}">
</div>
```

'''

models.py

'''

```
class Pictures(TimestampedModel):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.img)

class Post(TimestampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    lang = models.IntegerField(choices=LANGUAGES, default=1)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(PostCategoies, blank=True)
    img = models.ManyToManyField(Pictures, blank=True)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, help_text="Example: fa fa-info")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

'''

views.py

'''

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views import View
from .models import Post, Pictures
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from . import models
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class HomePageView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()[:4]
        context = {'posts': posts}
    
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)

class PostDetailView(DetailView):

    context_object_name = "post_detail"
    model = models.Post
    template_name = 'news.html'
```

'''

urls.py

'''

```
app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name=""),
    path('post-detail/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail")
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

'''

Comment: It looks like that particular post has an empty collection for the `img` field which is why `.first()/.first` is returning `None`.

Comment: @schillingt   but it has collection "/post-detail/6/<QuerySet [<Pictures: images/wallpaper002.jpg>, <Pictures: images/walpaper001.jpg>]>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the instance of a `Pictures` class with your current code. You need to then access the `img` property:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img class="detail_picture img-thumbnail" src="{{ post_detail.img.all.first.img.url }}">
</div>
```

I would also suggest that you protect against the case of not having an instance in the ManyToMany field

```
{% if post_detail.img.all.first %}
    <div class="text-center">
        <img class="detail_picture img-thumbnail" src="{{ post_detail.img.all.first.img.url }}">
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I'd also suggest looking into [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and/or [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) as a way to more efficiently fetch these related details. It will help you prevent N+1 queries. You can verify you're not running too many queries with the [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar).